# Does GDB have a userid?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, unix, gdb

I am trying to debug a C program using GDB. But when I try to run it from inside gdb I get the following error :

*note: the FATAL error line is user defined*

```
gdb-peda$ run 
Starting program: /home/masterdungeon/HTAOEBookPrograms/0x200/0x280/0x287/GameOfChance 


        **************** WELCOME to the GAME OF CHANCE *****************

    This game will essentially tell you how lucky you are today   ;)

---- New player ----
Please enter your name : user_gdb

[!!!] Fatal Error   in register_user() while opening  DATAFILE
: Permission denied
[Inferior 1 (process 10636) exited with code 0377]
Warning: not running
gdb-peda$
```

This program is actually a command line game named "GameOfChance" (from the book HTAOE). Whenever a user runs the program, the program first checks its UserID to see whether the user is already registered as a player in the DATAFILE. If there is no entry of that UID in the DATAFILE(i.e player not registered already), then the program allows to create a new player and accept a username, thus registering as a player with that UID and accepted username. But I think GDB does not have a UID since there is no entry of gdb in /etc/passwd. How do I make the program run while debugging and register GDB as a new player? Is it even possible ?

The code looks like this :

```
12   #define DATAFILE "/var/gameofchance.data" // File to store user data

46   int main(){

//lines of code

 53         uid = getuid(); // get current user_id i.e player_id
 54         player_exists = get_player_data(uid); // returns -1 if player does not exist 
 55                 //otherwise returns 0 and puts all player data into struct player
 56 
 57         if(player_exists == -1) {
 58                 register_player(uid);
 59         }

//lines of code

148         return 0;
149   } //end main()

314   void register_player(int uid){

//lines of code

327         fd = open(DATAFILE, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
329 
330         if(fd==-1){
331                 fatal("  in register_user() while opening  DATAFILE\n");
332         }

//lines of code

344 } //end register_player
```

the permissions for DATAFILE are :

`-rw------- 1 root masterdungeon 240 Apr 19 13:54 gameofchance.data`

the permissions for executable game GameOfChance are :

`-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 29064 Jan  4 19:45 GameOfChance`

Another thing I couldn't understand is when I set a breakpoint at line 54 and check for value of uid I get 1000 as UID of GDB.

```
Breakpoint 16, main () at gameofchance.c:54
54      player_exists = get_player_data(uid); // returns -1 if player does not exist
gdb-peda$ x/wd &uid
0x7ffd4ed4aee8: 1000
```

How's it possible that GDB has userid of 1000 ? as there is no entry of gdb in /etc/passwd. 1000 is userid of *masterdungeon*.

Okay so it works when gdb is run using `sudo gdb`. But why do I have to run it as *root* to get it run nicely **in GDB** ?

Otherwise in **BASH** the program runs successfully as user *masterdungeon*. Only in **GDB** it require to be run as *root*

Comment: no man I think the permission is 'setuid' which means the real userid will be of the user i.e 1000 and effective userid will be 0 (that of root).  Also when I execute on BASH it runs successfully with userid 1000. Why does it not run in GDB ?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/can-gdb-debug-suid-root-programs

Comment: Thanks man ! I guess my question was very long and boring :P  The question in the link you gave is very precise so is the answer. It solved my doubt. Thanks again!

Comment: Aside, it seems a little strange to give a game root privileges. Couldn't the executable and database both be owned by `masterdungeon`?

Comment: haha the thing is as I said the book HTAOE, it is about exploitation of programs. The game is just a sample program which has SUID and could be potentially exploited to gain root shell.

Answer (score 2):

> Does GDB have a userid?

Yes. Every process that runs, including GDB processes, has both an effective UID and a real UID.  Often these are the same.  But you seem to have a misunderstanding.  These do not describe the process itself.  Rather they describe the *user* on whose behalf the process is running.

> How's it possible that GDB has userid of 1000 ? as there is no entry of gdb in /etc/passwd. 1000 is userid of masterdungeon.

Because you're running `gdb` as user "masterdungeon", or as another user with the same UID number.

> Okay so it works when gdb is run using sudo gdb. But why do I have to run it as root to get it run nicely **in GDB** ?

Your data file is accessible only to root:

> ```
> -rw------- 1 root masterdungeon 240 Apr 19 13:54 gameofchance.data
> ```

.  When run directly, the program accommodates that by being root-owned and having its SUID bit set:

> ```
> -rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 29064 Jan  4 19:45 GameOfChance
> ```

(note the "s" in the first triad of permission bits).  That causes the program, *when run directly*, to run with the effective UID of root, even though root did not actually launch it.  This is one of the cases where the effective and real UIDs differ.  It is also a very poor use case for SUID, because SUID root programs present an existential security risk to the host system, and that risk is not justified for a game.

The risk would be *much* worse if the SUID bit were honored when the program is running under control of a debugger.  A debugger can make arbitrary changes to program data and even binary code while the program is running, and that would present an easy vector for privilege escalation if SUID were honored in such contexts. Accordingly, **the SUID bit on an executable has no effect when the program is run in a debugger**.  (See also [Can gdb debug suid root programs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15911/can-gdb-debug-suid-root-programs))

Thus, if you debug the program as a user other than root, it will not be able to open the data file, but if you use `sudo` to run the debugger then you obtain the needed privelege to access the data file through `sudo`, and the fact that the SUID bit on the executable is not honored is irrelevant.

**The best way to debug the program is in its build environment, before installation, such that it is owned by you and does not need (or have) its SUID bit set**.  This may require some manipulation of where or how it looks for its data file, which should also be owned by you.

---

As for how the program is installed, you have a tension between priorities:

- Programs available for all users to run should be owned by root and writable only by root, to make it difficult for other users to modify them or substitute different program for them, both of which could lead to data breach and (further) privilege escalation.
- You apparently require that users running the game program be able to write to a shared data file.  It's unclear what this file contains, but a shared high score list might be an example.
- But you do not (presumably) want to allow users to manipulate the data file arbitrarily, under their own authority, lest they cheat in some way, or worse.

The easiest approach would be to give each user their own, unshared data file, created at need by the program within the user's home directory, and accessible to that user.  Then you don't need to mess with SUID / SGID, nor do you need to have any concern about users interfering with each other.  Sure, they may be able to cheat, but it will affect only them.  And you will be able to debug the program with GDB.

If it is essential that the data file be both shared among program users and writable (via the program) to all of them, then a better approach than making the program SUID-root would be to make it SGID-some_group_not_root, and make the data file writable by that group.  Better still, avoid the SGID bit, and just require users to be members of the chosen group in order to use the program.  Do note that SGID is not honored when debugging, either.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and suggestions. Much appreciated. But the thing is the program is deliberately made susceptible to exploitation, why? To learn exploitation. It is deliberately given the SUID permission. But yes thanks for your concern and the details you provided are very informative :)